# How to input search query to get required image from JSON data?

Tags: javascript, json, themoviedb-api

I am currently building a web app using TMDB API when I type any movie name it should display me the poster of required movie. I am not getting how to search the required movie and get the URL of the poster. Links ->https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/movies/get-movie-images  and https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/configuration/get-api-configuration

My code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test app</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #fetch{
            position: absolute;
            text-align: center;
            left: 450px;
            top: 35px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<form name="fetch-movie-title" id="fetch">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a movie title" id="term" />
     <input type="submit" onclick="showdata()" id="search" value="Find me a poster" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

function showdata() {
    var film = document.getElementById('term').value;
    console.log(film);
}

    var requestURL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/9340/images?api_key=my-api-key";

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open('GET', requestURL);

    request.responseType = 'json';

    request.send();

    request.onload = function(){
        var myjsondata = request.response; //request.response contains all our JSON data 

        console.log(myjsondata);
        var str = "<img src = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500"+ myjsondata.posters[2].file_path +"'/>";
        console.log(str);
        document.write(str);
    } 

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what problem exactly you have.

Comment: @RDhaval I dont have problem I want to get poster of movie which I put it in the input eg: if I put movie name speed then it should display poster of movie speed.

Comment: @RDhaval you can check here -> https://github.com/frimmy/api-test I want to do the samething how can I get movie poster of required movie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test it as getting their API key requires too much hassle, but I guess what you need is [search call](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/search/search-movies):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test app</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #fetch{
            position: absolute;
            text-align: center;
            left: 450px;
            top: 35px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<form name="fetch-movie-title" id="fetch">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a movie title" id="term" />
     <input type="submit" onclick="showdata()" id="search" value="Find me a poster" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

function showdata() {
    var film = document.getElementById('term').value;
    console.log(film);

    var requestURL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=<<api_key>>&language=en-US&query="+film+"&page=1&include_adult=false";

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open('GET', requestURL);

    request.responseType = 'json';

    request.send();

    request.onload = function(){
        var myjsondata = request.response; //request.response contains all our JSON data 

        console.log(myjsondata);
        var str = "<img src = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500"+ myjsondata.results[0].poster_path+"'/>";
        console.log(str);
        document.write(str);
    } 

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

See this link -> https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/search/search-movies and then click on try it using your api-key as well as search query.

Comment: Salacinski Where should I insert search query in this URL -> `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=<<api_key>>&language=en-US&page=1&include_adult=false`

Comment: Look at my example - there's another parameter - "query" -     `var requestURL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=<<api_key>>&language=en-US&query="+film+"&page=1&include_adult=false";`

Comment: Salcinski yes there is a parameter called query in table which is required but how do you came to know where it must be inserted.

Comment: go to [THEIR DOCS](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/search/search-movies), click "Try it out", click field next to "query" and type something, then below they'll give you example request URL.

Comment: this answer works fine.. I verified it placing `api_key` and `speed`. https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=f634a87e693f6900f7bb353ae330d606&language=en-US &query=speed&page=1&include_adult=false

Comment: @MichałSałaciński please review your comment that I have edited the URL for search query was missing now I have upvoted and solved that issue after editing that comment.

Comment: @MichałSałaciński How can I handle spaces if I give query as Iron Man then how will it handle space in try it block in DOCS I can see they substitute %20 for space in between.

Comment: Yup, it's named "encoding" and you can encode a string for param like `encodeURIComponent(film)`, wich will change spaces to "%20", along with several other things.